# Where is the mistake? (Can't be specific because I have no clue... :/ )

Tags: jquery, iteration, this, attr, each

### Goal

I was trying to get jQuery to output the class name of the parent container as text in a nested container. To be more specific, I wanted all text in each `<p>` to be styled with a different font. That's easy enough, I just assigned classes. But I also wanted a `<span>` in each `<p>` to show the used font (simply by adding the parents' class name as text).

### Examples/Tests

[THIS link shows the not-working page](http://www.cgeese.de/tests/webfonts/index.html)

Weirdly enough,

[THIS jsfiddle test (kinda*) works](http://jsfiddle.net/qrFMY/4/)

### (a bit of the) Code

The second link is also very convenient when checking the code, so I hope it's ok if I only paste the jquery-stuff in here (I find it very likely that I messed that part up... again...)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("span").each(function() {
         var usedfont= $(this).parent().attr("class");
         $(this).text(usedfont);
      });
   });
</script>
```

### My train of thoughs:

1. when dom is loaded,
2. iterate through all span-elements,
3. setting a variable as the class name of the parents' element and
4. setting the text of the span-element as this variable.(ergo echoing
   out the parents' class name).

### Question(s)

Why won't the page behind the first link work? And why does the jsfiddle test deliver?

***** Why does the jsfiddle-result start out with `});//]]>`?

**Thanks a bunch!**

Comment: I get two errors from your website: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` (for jquery) which leads to `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. The jquery library is not loaded so it can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: http://www.cgeese.de/tests/webfonts/js/jquery-1.7.min.js is a 404.

Edit: Your jsfiddle is having issues because there's no need to use the `<script>` tags in the JavaScript portion of the fiddle. All the code there will be interpreted as javascript. Just use jQuery as an external dependency (with the list on the left) and strip out the `script` tags enclosing your own JS.

Comment: oh my god, I am so ashamed. I was so sure I linked to google.

Comment: It's OK. I've had instants where I was literally stuck on something for an hour, started to explain the problem to someone else, and by explaining it suddenly realized the very obvious cause of my problem without them even saying anything. :-)

Answer (score 1):

And the jsfiddle is ok too. The "weird stuff" on the top comes from your code (manual inserting `script` tags and jQuery into the javascript section of a fiddle already using jQuery)